# StoreKit Error when restoring in app purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am attempting to set up in app purchases, and I am getting the following error

Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn't be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)"

I am testing purchases in the sandbox (with test user account)

It only seems to do this on one of my devices though - I am able to restore purchases correctly, without error message on my iPad (iOS 7.0.2), but when I try to use my iPhone (4s iOS 7.0.2) the error message persists. I should also probably note that I am able to purchase in app purchases using my phone with the same iTunes account (so it seems the store is accessible??)

I have had a pretty comprehensive search around SO and google, and have found some very similar error messages but none quite the same, and without success.

Things I have tried;

- Restarting the phone Deleting the app - and reloading (several times)
- I am using a test user account set up on itunesconnect
- I have logged out of itunes on my regular account on the phone (under
  "settings/itunes & app store")
- I have logged in using the test user account
- I have created a new test user account and logged in using the new
  account
- I have reset the network settings.

I think there might be more but that's all I can think of at the moment.

I haven't included any code but can if anyone thinks its relevant (although as it works on another device, I'm thinking it must be a setting on my phone).

---

Edit:
I tried the same app (and the same test user account) on another iPhone 4s (iOS7) which worked correctly (so I ruled out specific phone compatibility).
The iPhone with the issue is an iPhone I previously had installed the iOS7 betas on - although I have changed it over to the GM version (although restored from a previous backup to keep data etc) so I was wondering if it might be related to this in some way?
- I did a complete restore - and once again backed up using an iCloud backup - which did not fix the issue...
however...
doing a full restore and setting up as a new iPhone DID RESOLVE THE ISSUE!!!
Then I plugged the phone back into my mac, and restored from a previous backup - and it still works...
I'm still not certain which aspect of the iOS was causing the issue - but hopefully this might help anyone else facing similar unexplained issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short a full backup of the phone - back to factory settings has fixed the issue.

1. Make sure you have a backup of everything you dont want to lose!!
2. Backup to factory defaults
3. Set up as if it's a new device (test the in App Purchase here by logging out of normal account and logging into test account from within the app, proceed if it works)
4. Plug into Mac and restore to a previous backup
5. Test the in-app-purchase as previously.

A few things to note -

I restored my phone twice before it started to play ball, the first time I set it up from a backup straight away, the second time I set it up as a new device, tested the in app purchase (which seemed to recover the issue) then I restored the backup, and it (fortunately) continues to work.

The phone I was having problems with was the phone I installed the iOS7 betas on. I think I read somewhere that the in app purchase wont work on a beta OS, but I had transferred to the GM release so I figured that wouldn't be the issue.

I'm still not certain if that is the cause, or just a coincidence, however it seemed to work for me, and hopefully it will help anyone else having the same issue in the future.